# Can TFS Work Item Icons be Changed?

Tags: tfs, icons, tfs-workitem, tfs-web-access

How can you change the icon that represents a work item type in TFS Web Access?  For instance, a bug appears as a page with a red squiggly line, while a task is a page with a red check mark.  These look a bit too similar to us, and we'd like to differentiate them with different colored icons.  I suppose we could replace the image on the TFS server with another, but what if you only wanted to replace these in a single team project?

Comment: How about asking the developers on that specific project to use the screen magnifier for clearer distinction between work-item types?

Comment: A lightly more long-winded way would be to use the TFS API (which is pretty simple) and knock together a simple interface web app to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the colours of the icon by updating the `<WorkItemColors>` configuration, as described in this answer:

- [How to change work item icons in on-premise Azure DevOps 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959927/how-to-change-work-item-icons-in-on-premise-azure-devops-2019)

The link is for TFS/Azure Dev Ops 2019, but does work for earlier versions.

The result is something like this:

[image: Example coloured work items]

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to TFS2010 which uses two completely different icons for bugs and tasks, but if that is not an option I would definitely go with just changing the gifs on the server.